Slow render action 0/3 in @Preview Android Studio LadyBug
Broke Android Studio when previewing


package com.example.alectrico

import ...
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AlectricoTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
                ) {
                    Greeting()
                    /*BakingScreen()*/
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String = "alectrico", modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Surface(color = Color.Cyan) {
        Text(
            text = "Hi, my name is $name!",

        )
    }
}
@Preview
@Composable
fun SimpleComposablePreview() {
    Greeting()
}




In the rol of testing my new kotlin app
As I don't want to start runing virtual devices
I put @Preview on the function
So I can see the preview instead the real output
Android Studio LadyBug
But I broke Android Studio with
Slow render action 0/3
